# Using basepath view helper inside module bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework2

I'd like to access the `basePath` view helper `inside my Application Module Bootstrap.`

Here's the current code in my Application Module:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
   $viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewhelpermanager');
   $basePath = $viewHelperManager->get('BasePath');        
   $headScript = $viewHelperManager->get('HeadScript');
   $headScript->appendFile($basePath->basePath('/js/custom.js'));
}
```

**I'm able to get the head script view helper to add the javascript but i cannot get access to the base path view helper**

If you look at the code, the call is: `$basePath->basePath('/js/custom.js')`.

How do I accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way you were fetching the helper in your question, the only problem is the way you're trying to call the helper method.

The BasePath view helper is an invokable class, you can either call its `__invoke()` method explicitly

```
$basePath = $viewHelperManager->get('BasePath');

$basePath->__invoke('js/custom.js');
```

or, since declaring the invoke method allows you to call an object as if it were a function you can write the same thing like this

```
$basePath = $viewHelperManager->get('BasePath');

$basePath('js/custom.js');
```

Comment: What exactly does invoke do?

Comment: `__invoke` is a magic method that is called when you run the class itself like a function. i.e. `$basePath($arg);`

Answer (score -2):

```
$viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewhelpermanager');       
$headScript = $viewHelperManager->get('HeadScript');        
$headScript->prependFile($viewHelperManager->getRenderer()->basePath('js/bootstrap.min.js'));
$headScript->prependFile($viewHelperManager->getRenderer()->basePath('js/jquery.min.js'));
$headScript->prependFile($viewHelperManager->getRenderer()->basePath('js/respond.min.js'),'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9'));
$headScript->prependFile($viewHelperManager->getRenderer()->basePath('js/html5shiv.min.js'),'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9'));
```